# How To Binding To Path And Then Redirect?

Tags: asp.net, .net, repeater, datalist

First Of all, Excuse me for my bad english!
I Use C# Lang + Asp.Net At .Net FrameWork v4.0

I Want To Make A Dynamic Page, In That, I Read Some Values from DB Table and then Create Some Buttons.

Per Record of my Table have a Button On RunTime.
Now, I want Bind My Data Using **DataList** and In ItemTemplate I Use Button. In The Name And Text Of Buttons isn't any problem.

My Problem Is in Binding String Of a Path to My Onclick Event And Then Redirect to This Path OnClick Of Button.(This String Path is a field in My DB Table)

In Addition I'm in Hate of Javascript. I Use Internet Explorer < v8 and It Has Problem with Run a Javascript Command !

I Want A Way to Redirect With Code-Behind Methods ...

This My DataList :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" 
DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceMainCat">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatName") %>' 
        CssClass="Maininput" OnClick=??? />
</ItemTemplate>
```

This Image Show Buttons I Want Dynamicly Set Redirect Method to Them :

[image: DataList Buttons In ItemTemplate]

Comment: Could you please share your work or whatever you have tried? Its hard to understand what you have explained?

Comment: I dont understand the language which is written in it. :-(

Comment: My Language isn't Important :D
I Want Redirecting To Other page, When Click On Buttons in DataList.

Answer (score 0):

I Found The Answer !

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" 
DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceMainCat">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="LinkBtn" CssClass="Maininput" Text='<%# Eval("CatName") %>' runat="server" 
        PostBackUrl='<%# string.Concat("~/Admin/MainCats/" , Eval("CatLinkName")) %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Using PostBackUrl is Answer, Cheer :)